# Why htop shows that total % CPU usage of processes is more than 400% on a 4 core/4 thread system?

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-usage, htop

I'm running some intensive tasks on my Linux (Manjaro) server and the CPU is at 100% of all its cores, but I saw that the percentages of CPU use per process sum to a much higher number than 400% on my 4 core/4 thread system.

[image: Part of the htop screen]

If I'd count other processes not shown on the screenshot it would sum up to something like 700-800%. The selected process is not at 400% all the time, but even when it isn't, it and other processes still sum to more than 400%.

EDIT:

```
$ inxi -C
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core i5-3470 bits: 64 type: MCP cache: L2: 1024 KiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 3473 min/max: 1600/3600 cores: 1: 3498 2: 3509 3: 3397 4: 3490
```

Comment: This only means some process or sub-process are waiting,  it is not really 400%  as a "mathematical" view of what is a "%"    a process runing 8 sub process on 2 cores will do that a process runing 8 sub process on 8 cores "can" and only "can" be affected on 8 cores independtly then it is still the same but 100% only ...  you can manage your processus by the `taskset` command to specify an application to use dedicated cores if needed for exampel a BDD on cores 1-2 all a webpage on core 3 and keeping core 0 for general purpose

Comment: 400% to a… sleeping task . OMG!

Comment: @MC68020  I would assume the sleep state is momentary, and is due to `htop` itself being scheduled to produce this report.

Comment: If 4 processors produce 800% total cycles, then your assertion that these are single-core processors must be suspect. Can you add the output from `inxi -C` to your question?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Added. But usually it maxes out at 400% total as it should. I don't think it was capping at exactly 800% in the screenshot above.